# Sec_to_Time function does not work with LIMIT function in mysql

Tags: mysql

If I use:

`SELECT Sec_to_Time(Sum(Time_to_Sec(time_utilize))) as week_time FROM attendance WHERE staff_id = 'ahmed'`

it works fine but when I use:

```
SELECT Sec_to_Time(Sum(Time_to_Sec(time_utilize))) as week_time FROM attendance WHERE staff_id = 'ahmed' LIMIT 1, 7
```

it say:

> MySQL returned an empty result set
>   (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0004
>   sec )

though the attendance table contains almost 20 records against 'admed' ...........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes SUM is an aggregate function so we can get our desired result by using BETWEEN operator like:

```
SELECT Sec_to_Time(Sum(Time_to_Sec(time_utilize))) as week_time FROM attendance WHERE staff_id = 'ahmed' AND today BETWEEN '2011-06-1' AND '2011-06-7'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because that query will always return a single record for 'ahmed' and this is because you are using SUM aggregate. So when you do a LIMIT 1,7 it returns an empty result set.

Try doing LIMIT 0 and it should work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: oops yap ;) now I do not need it because I was doing so for problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395689/how-to-sum-total-time-utilize-in-each-week-of-a-month but now it's fine. Thanks

Comment: cool! I guessed so that this query seems related to that post but I thought it's good to respond anyways :-)